# Disable responsiveness in Bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented this simple web typing game www.fastypingcontest.com which is based on Bootstrap CSS. I am trying to disable the responsiveness as explained in the tutorial http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive But there has to be something I am missing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what have you done!? Can you post some code?

Comment: removed the meta tags; defined the container like this <div class="container" style="max-width:none !important; width:970px;>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify only `col-xs-*` classes on your columns. Every size above that will then also follow the same rules.

To clarify: all columns missing a `col-xs-*` class are still defaulting to the 100% width of the container on mobile sizes.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't get the col-xs should have been the only one.